# How do I configure Undertow's MAX_PARAMETERS setting in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, undertow

I would like to configure Undertow’s `MAX_PARAMETERS` value in an application that uses the Quarkus MyFaces extension for JSF.

I could not find any `application.properties` settings that would be forwarded to Undertow, nor does there appear to be any API to customize the `UndertowOptionMap`.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not an expert here, but I believe that the option you're looking for isn't available in Quarkus's version of Undertow. This is because in Quarkus, Undertow is purely a servlet container, the HTTP transport is handled by Vert.x, which has different configuration options. For configurable HTTP limits, see https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#http-limits-configuration

Comment: @Ladicek I see.  I'm running into `io.undertow.util.ParameterLimitException`, though, and there doesn't appear to be a setting related to parameter limits per se, so I'll open a feature request on the Quarkus GitHub, then.

Comment: Yea it seems the `UndertowOptionMap` is hardcoded to be empty in the Vert.x implementation: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-http/blob/3.1.0.Beta1/vertx/src/main/java/io/undertow/vertx/VertxHttpExchange.java#L794 Feature request makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Quarkus 1.13.0, this be done by setting the `quarkus.servlet.max-parameters` configuration value.